# Using Persistent Volumes in Docker

Tags: docker, persistent-storage

I have a Docker container running on my Mac. This Docker container has a home folder like:

```
/home/my_user/my_project/
```

It is based on a Ubuntu OS image and running on my Mac. When I run this container, the container constantly updates a folder under the my_project folder. Now when I stop and remove this container, it just gets erased and when I start a new instance of the container, the process has to begin all over again, i.e., the container starts writing into the my_project folder, but the old files which it already wrote is completely lost.

How can I make the data written by the container be persistent even after a container delete / restart?

Docker persistent volumes is what I understand that I need, but how can I mount a local folder on my Mac such that the data is written and persisted? This container could run on a Windows machine, so how can I make a persistent volume across different OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start your container with the `-v` flag. So if you were to mount the `/home/my_user/my_project` directory from the container onto the host to `/srv/my_app/data` for example, you'd need to use it as follows:

```
docker run -v /srv/my_app/data:/home/my_user/my_project IMAGE_NAME
```

There's also a difference between volumes and bind mounts, which I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150829/what-is-the-difference-between-binding-mounts-and-volumes-while-handling-persist/47152658#47152658)